# How to block a phone from using my WiFi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, android, blocking

How do I block my son's phone from using my home WiFi network? Can it be done by blocking the MAC address of my son's phone?

Comment: You can do this through your router either by IP or MAC address. Could also change the password. More information would be needed (like your router) to go into further detail.

Comment: Ask your neighbor to log into the router and block the IP/MAC address of the phone and you're done.

Comment: realtek rtl8191se is a MIMO wireless LAN chip. IPv4 is a form of IP address. The other is IPv6. Getting a bit off topic now. Once again. Need to know your router or we can't help you.

Comment: so to summarize: You want to secretly change the setting on a device that does not belong to you (legal issues?), while not knowing basic network terms like "IPv4" or "router". I am guessing that your plan will not work out unless you significantly increase the quality of your question.

Comment: its an linksys router

Answer (score 6):

You could just change the WIFI security password and don't tell your son the new password.

Answer (score 2):

In your home wireless/router you should be able to block the access to the wifi with the mac address. But the way to do it depend on the router model.

Comment: how can i disable mac address

Answer (score 0):

If your router is `D-Link` you can follow these steps: (It's almost same in other routers)

1. Go to your router config page. (Type `192.168.1.1` in your web browser and enter your router password. Default username and password is `admin`)
2. In `Advanced Setup` menu, choose `Parental Control`
3. Then click on `Add` and enter the needed information.
4. Finally click on `Apply/Save`.

[image]

---

You can also block a MAC Address using wireless menu(`192.168.1.1 -> Wireless -> MAC Filter`)